# how to Extract Multi Node XML in spring integration

Tags: xpath, spring-integration

could some one point me to any examples on how i can extract multi node xml, i have the below sample example and which can come in multiple nodes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<m1:GetBankDetails xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m1="xxxx">
<ns1:PARAMS>
    <m1:ID/>
    <m1:CHECK_NUM>00000294</m1:CHECK_NUM>
    <m1:VENDOR_NAME>America</m1:VENDOR_NAME>
    <m1:COUNTRY>US</m1:COUNTRY>
    <m1:CURRENCY>USD</m1:CURRENCY>
    <m1:PAYMENT_AMOUNT>10000.0</m1:PAYMENT_AMOUNT>
    <m1:CHECK_STATUS>O</m1:CHECK_STATUS>
    <m1:BANK_ACC_NAME>Bank Of America</m1:BANK_ACC_NAME>
    <m1:BANK_ACC_NUM>3359327056</m1:BANK_ACC_NUM>
</ns1:PARAMS>
<ns1:PARAMS>
    <m1:ID/>
    <m1:CHECK_NUM>000002</m1:CHECK_NUM>
    <m1:VENDOR_NAME>China</m1:VENDOR_NAME>
    <m1:COUNTRY>US</m1:COUNTRY>
    <m1:CURRENCY>USD</m1:CURRENCY>
    <m1:PAYMENT_AMOUNT>10000.0</m1:PAYMENT_AMOUNT>
    <m1:CHECK_STATUS>O</m1:CHECK_STATUS>
    <m1:BANK_ACC_NAME>Bank Of China</m1:BANK_ACC_NAME>
    <m1:BANK_ACC_NUM>3359327056</m1:BANK_ACC_NUM>
</ns1:PARAMS>
</m1:GetBankDetails>
```

Any help with sample code is greatly appreciated

Comment: Be more specific, please. Do you want to have an `xPath` for that XML? What do you need to extract?

Comment: yeah extract all the elements, see in the example <PARAMS> can come more than once and how do i map the extract output to an user defined object

Comment: OK. it's closer already. Can you show how does it relate to the Spring Integration? Do you know what is `Marhsaller` (JaxB, Castor etc.)?